# htaccess redirect if the url does not contain a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

With htaccess I need to redirect all URLs that don't contain a specific URL path (healthcare) to a new domain while keeping the original URL intact.

Example:

healthcare.domain.com/anydirectory/anything.html

should redirect to

staging.domain.com/anydirectory/anything.html

but any URL containing /healthcare should not get redirected. As in healthcare.domain.com/industries/healthcare/customers.html should not be redirected.

Both domains are on the same server and healthcare.domain.com is pointed to same root as staging.domain.com. They wanted to be able to access the following page staging.domain.com/industries/healthcare/ at healthcare.domain.com. I setup healthcare.domain.com as a new subdomain pointing its root to the same root as staging.domain.com. I then setup a redirect in the htaccess for healthcare.domain.com to redirect to healthcare.domain.com/industries/healthcare which works perfectly, but if you click anywhere else on the site outside of /industries/healthcare/ I need to bring the user back to staging.domain.com/whatever

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^healthcare\.domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.healthcare\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/healthcare\.domain\.com\/industries\/healthcare\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^healthcare\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/healthcare/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

But the above always returns http://staging.domain.com/index.php

Comment: Are `healthcare.domain.com` and `staging.domain.com` on same host and same `VirtualHost`?

Comment: I added more to the question above to answer yours.

Comment: Is `staging.domain.com/industries/healthcare/` same as `healthcare.domain.com/industries/healthcare/`?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why `http://staging.domain.com/whatever` was always redirecting to `http://staging.domain.com/index.php`?  I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^healthcare\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/healthcare/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I had one that was almost identical to yours and it returned the same results - it just gave me staging.domain.com/index.php. I added more information to my question above that may shed more light on why.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?healthcare\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/healthcare/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?healthcare\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://healthcare.domain.com/industries/healthcare/ [R=302,L]
```