# .htaccess headache: redirect root folder to A, these folders to B, ignore the rest

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

The website is structured to have the main language (`fi`) in the root folder and other language versions in subfolders. The site consists of static HTML files in real folders, not virtual. Here I have on the first line a rule which works, and redirects all traffic that target those three folders. However, the 2nd line does not do what I want.

```
RedirectMatch permanent "(se|pl|en)\/(.+)?" https://www.example.com/example
RedirectMatch permanent "(!lv|!ee)\/?(.+)?" https://www.example.com/another-example
```

- So, root directory needs to be redirected to url `A`
- Subfolders `se`, `pl` and `en` need to be redirected to url `B`
- Subfolders `lv` and `ee` must be ignored.

Comment: So `url A` is folder `/a`?

Comment: No. Edited for clarification. Example.com is another server.

Comment: If "lv and ee must be ignored" why are you writing a rule for them? I think you should clarify even more.

Comment: @horcrux I wanted to have a not-rule. Not lv. Not ee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you can use these rules with regex anchors:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# se|pl|en redirection
RewriteRule ^(se|pl|en) https://www.example.com/example/ [L,R=302,NC]

# anything other than /ee and /lv
RewriteRule !^(ee|lv)/ https://www.example.com/another-example/ [L,R=302,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing these changes.

Comment: Almost. Also anything in the root directory must be redirected. For example /any-file-name.html I tried like this:
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/.+\.html$ https://www.example.com/example`
...but it breaks the se|pl|en redirection. It will not reach there.

Comment: Sorry, no. That does not work. If rules are in that order, second rule will never be reached, because first rule matches all the subfolders.

Comment: I have changed the order of rules however do note that `/el/abcd` will not match root folder rule due to anchors

Comment: I utilized this answer by you (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21761345/1383913) and got it to work.

Comment: I used `RedirectMatch` only because your code already had it. Otherwise I always prefer writing `Mod_rewrite` rules myself.  btw your rule #2 will **redirect anything** that doesn't start with `/ee` and `/lv` not just root URIs. So it will redirect `/foo/bar/baz` to `another-example/` also. Anyway I have translated rules from your answer to simpler `Mod_rewrite` code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got to work by forgetting `RedirectMatch` and using `RewriteCond` + `RewriteRule` instead.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(se|pl|en)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/example/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(ee|lv)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/another-example/ [L,R=302]
```

Applied from anubhava's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21761345/1383913